# Генерация чисел по заданному диапазону PHP

Tags: php

Цель, создать текстовый файл при помощи php, с последовательностью цифр о 4444 до 49999.

Comment: А в чем сложность? Как создать файл или как прогнать цикл for ?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать любой из циклов, к примеру:

```
$file="ПУТЬ/ДО/ФАЙЛА";
$numbers=array();
$number=4444;
$end=49999;
while($number<=$end){
$number++;
array_push($numbers,$number);
}
file_put_contents($file, implode(" ",$numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```
file_put_contents('1.txt', implode("\n", range(4444, 49999)));
```